# Sort array and remove duplicates without sort function

Tags: javascript

How can I remove an duplicate from an array whilst I have a function sorting it.
I've used the bubble sort function but when I try to use other functions to remove the duplicates an error is called.

```js
function sortarray(array) {
  var done = false;
  while (!done) {
    done = true;
    for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i += 1) {
      if (array[i - 1] > array[i]) {
        done = false;
        var tmp = array[i - 1];
        array[i - 1] = array[i];
        array[i] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }
  return array;
}

var numbers = [100, 100, 13, 1, 47, 50];
sortarray(numbers);
console.log(numbers)
```

Comment: @DenizYakupCelik what error you got and why `sort` function cannot be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove duplicated items from an array you can use this example.

```
// Defining function to get unique values from an array
function getUnique(array){
    var uniqueArray = [];
    
    // Loop through array values
    for(i=0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(uniqueArray.indexOf(array[i]) === -1) {
            uniqueArray.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return uniqueArray;
}

var names = ["John", "Peter", "Clark", "Harry", "John", "Alice"];
var uniqueNames = getUnique(names);
console.log(uniqueNames);
```

Check this tutorial: [https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-javascript-array.php#:~:text=Answer%3A%20Use%20the%20indexOf(),from%20an%20array%20in%20JavaScript](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-javascript-array.php#:%7E:text=Answer%3A%20Use%20the%20indexOf(),from%20an%20array%20in%20JavaScript).

Comment: thank you very muchBut how do I incorporate this function in the function I already have

Comment: because it needs to wort and remove duplicates at the same time. I did before hand have a function that removed duplicates, but I don't know how I can use both functions at the same time

Comment: @DenizYakupCelik Your function return a sorted array, so you can use it as a parameter for this function console.log(getUnique(sortarray(numbers))).

Comment: I've tried it. And I can't show you the code

Comment: @DenizYakupCelik Make sure that you did everything correctly I just checked a code, it works correctly and returns result [1, 13, 47, 50, 100].

Comment: Can I see how you did it somehow im really struggling.

Comment: @DenizYakupCelik Check the code here. http://pastie.org/p/4uzGbx9KZ3dcn2KfQCqOtI